Get first mint txn and total minted amount for SPL token using web3.js
The value for total supply returned by getMint() or metaplex metadata is the same value shown on the block explorer front end, but I want to find the initial minted amount before any burning. For one example, total supply on the block explorer says 999,361,623.83 but if you look at the first mint txn found on birdeye.so it shows 1,000,000,000 as the minted amount.
How can I return the first mint txn, initial mint amount, and also the best method to return the sum of all mints so far?
Thanks and best regards

You'll need to iterate through all transactions that involve this mint with getSignaturesForAddress followed by getTransaction, then parse through all instructions for any MintTo instruction using that mint.
