Determining when an NFT was first minted
Is there a way to determine when an NFT was created/minted? Preferably on-chain or if not, off-chain

https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/12647/get-first-mint-txn-and-total-minted-amount-for-spl-token-using-web3-js/13851 should answer the bulk of your question. But there's no way to access that information on-chain
